# Wifi Manager for windows phone[RT] application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, wifimanager

I have develop windows phone[RT] application , that List of all devices which are connected in same network which I my device is connected same like Wifi Manager in android . 
Is if possible in Windows phone c# application ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the [NetworkInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207293) Class. This class provides all the details related to Network connections(WIFI/Mobile).